# Apache2 + Perl

Tags: apache, perl

Как мне сделать поддержку перл скриптов в апаче, у меня Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи модуля mod_perl.

**Дополнено.**

- [Установка mod_perl на сервер](http://feofilaktov.ru/page/ustanovka-mod_perl-na-server)
- Но лучше на английском языке: [Install Configure Apache Localhost Perl on Linux Ubuntu](http://www.blog.highub.com/perl/install-configure-apache-localhost-perl-on-linux-ubuntu/)

Comment: Возможно вы знаете подробную инструкцию как это сделать (на русском) , а то мои поиски неудачны .

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо , помогла английская статья .

Answer (score 1):

Я бы очень рекомендовал посмотреть на предмет использования FastCGI.

Для его использования следует просто установить эти пакеты:

```
libapache2-mod-fastcgilibfcgi-perl
```

А на самом деле надо уточнить вопрос. Для чего Вам нужна поддержка Perl? Если у Вас есть какие-то готовые скрипты на Perl, то они могут не заработать. Скрипты для mod_perl и для FastCGI вообще говоря довольно серьезно отличаются.